# Telerik sometimes wont navigate to a url

Tags: c#, telerik

I am using Telerik for test automation, but sometimes (actually quite often) the NavigateTo() wont open the url.

I am using IE8.

can you also tell the supported Chorme and firefox versions

thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this [support case](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/automated-testing/webaii/simple-ie-8-navigateto-fails.aspx)...

Comment: One thing I've often found is that if the url you are navigating from isn't explicit, e.g. you haven't specified which exact file to open in the url (e.g. "admin/" instead of "admin/default.aspx") the various functions won't work. I'm not sure why this is but I've found I've had to employ javascript and other work arounds to pick up these cases.